# Android Google maps transparency

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, transparent

I'm working on a mapping app. And I want to show some views under the MapView.
I'm using the method:

```
    mapView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Nothing happens to the mapView. When I try to apply this method to my buttons it works fine, even applying it to the parent view of the mapView makes every child view transparent except for the mapView.

How can we make the mapView transparent? I have looked into other questions here  and I cant seem to find a solution.

Is there some special method in the mapView.getMap() that we can use to make it transparent?

Comment: I don't think you could achieve that with the mapview... even being a ViewGroup, Google adds a lot of things to it. Try to use another map library or rethink your UI/UX. BTW... why would you want something like that, will look really bad if can be achieve.

Comment: ^ what he said, that will look bad anyways. Avoid this idea like the plague.. instead make the things on top be transparent (buttons, icons, etc...)

Comment: I know it will look bad, but how will you achieve it though? What does Google add to it that makes it always opaque? What other map library would be the best alternative? @MarianoZorrilla

Comment: Here you have a list of libraries: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android but, again... try to avoid that kind of UI.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the transparence for the map using `View.setAlpha()` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float))). Here is a working example:

**activity_maps.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="THIS TEXT IS VISIBLE"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Marker m = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        m.showInfoWindow();

        View v = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
        v.setAlpha(0.5f); // Change this value to set the desired alpha
    }
}
```

The result looks like this (as you see the text is visible because of the map's transparency):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the setAlpha(float) method of your MapView reference, like this:

```
mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
mMapView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

If you are using MapFragment, then just use setAlpha(float) for your MapFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Framelayout where you put your 2 Views (CameraView and MapView) over themselfes.
And use the xml attribute alpha to make the MapView transparent.